# KeyListener doesnt work when I open another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, focus, keylistener

I want to solve a problem that I have a keylistener in a window.

I have a Main window in which I can perfectly use the KeyListeners, but when I open another JFrame they stop working, not even closing that second JFrame starts working again.

I have tried some solutions that I have found around here like:

1.

```
myframe.toFront();
```

2. 

```
myframe.requestFocus();
```

3. 

```
myframe.getTopLevelAncestor().requestFocus();
```

But none of them work. I hope you can help me with this problem

Comment: *but when I open another JFrame they stop working,* - a KeyListener will only work o a component that has focus. Whatever component you are adding the KeyListener to is losing focus and not getting focus back, even when the second window is closed. Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. A `Key Binding` will allow you to invoke an Action even if the component doesn't have focus. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Comment: @camickr Just tried the Key Bindings, but the same happens, the KeyBindings stopped working when I open that second JFrame.

Comment: Then you are doing it incorrectly. There are 3 different InputMaps, You need to add the binding to the appropriate InputMap. The one that works even if the component doesn't have focus. Post a proper [mre] is you need more help.

Comment: @camickr Okay, the problem was that I didnt not put the `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`Thanks